# how to call a template to edit a tei stylesheet

Tags: xslt, stylesheet, epub

I'm trying to automatically make epubs with a list of names after the body section.. In order to do this, I'm changing the tei stylesheet.
First, I tryed to insert this code in the "to.xsl" file, inside the "profiles/default/epub" folder:

```
  <xsl:template match="tei:body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:element name="back" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
      <xsl:element name="div" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
        <xsl:for-each select="//tei:rs[@type='luogo']">
          <xsl:element name="p" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

In this case the output shows the list of names before the body section.
Then I found the "bodyHook" template that you can see [here](http://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-xsl-common2/slides/teihtml-slides3.html), but it doesn't work (or I don't understand how to use it).
I tried to write something like this:

```
  <xsl:param name="indiceNomi"> 
    <back>
    <div>
      <xsl:for-each select="//tei:rs[@type='luogo']">
        <p>

          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </back>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="tei:body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:call-template name="bodyHook"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="creaIndice" select="$indiceNomi"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

But it is incorrect (seems that xsl:with-param can't be inside xsl:template, even if I saw some example like this).
So, if this is my input file, what kind of code I have to write?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/prova2.xsl"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiHeader><fileDesc>
        <titleStmt>
            <title>AA</title>
        </titleStmt>
        <publicationStmt><p><!-- supply publication information --></p></publicationStmt>
        <sourceDesc>
            <bibl>AA</bibl>
        </sourceDesc>
    </fileDesc><profileDesc>
        <langUsage>
            <language ident="ita">AA</language>
            <language ident="lat">AA</language>
        </langUsage>
    </profileDesc></teiHeader>
    <text>
        <body>
            <div type="book" n="3" xml:id="L3">
                <head>AA
                </head>
                <div type="capitolo" n="1" xml:id="L3-01">
                    <head>AA</head>
                    <p>AA
                        <pb n="200"/>textt<rs type="luogo">Genova</rs>texttex ttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext<rs type="luogo">London</rs>exttextte<rs type="luogo">Paris</rs>
                        texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext<rs type="luogo">Tokyo</rs>xttexttexttexttexttexttexttext<rs type="luogo">New York</rs>
                        <rs type="luogo">Dublin</rs><rs type="luogo">Moscow</rs><rs type="luogo">Cairo</rs>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

Thanks in advance, it will help me a lot to have some answer.

Comment: It's hard to believe that your first example actually produced the output you describe:  it should have produced a 'back' and 'div' element containing your list *after*, not before, the body element.  Are you sure you diagnosed your problem correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is really strange. The output was fine in another file, even without using a TEI stylesheet.
I see that it writes the section that I'm adding in the "index.html" section, and creates a empty body section before the one I wrote (this stylesheet creates an epub).
If I write this code in the "core.xsl" or "tei-to-epub.xsl" file, the output is the same (it still writes the list that I'm adding in the index section, creating a empty body section before it).
That's because my output doesn't have to be in the index file, but in the files after it (they're usually called "L1, L2, ...").

Comment: So I'm somehow trying to force the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood somewhat how to customize the TEI XSLT behavior. You're not supposed to modify the predefined files. The top of [this page](http://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-xsl-common/customize.html) gives a simple explanation. Basically the idea is that you would create your own XSLT file that imports the `tei.xsl` file, and add your own templates to your own XSLT file to customize the behavior.  For example, to define a template to be inserted at the end of the `<body>` section, you would add something like this to your XSLT file:

```
<xsl:template name="bodyEndHook">
  <back>
    <div>
      <xsl:for-each select="//tei:rs[@type='luogo']">
        <p>

          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </back>
</xsl:template>
```

Presumably, the TEI transform automatically calls this template at the end of the `<body>`.  The default behavior for `bodyEndHook` is to do nothing, but you can override that default behavior by adding your own templat.